# Python ValueError: too many values to unpack with dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on a file that needs to readout excel rows. I have made to seperate files. one where i define functions and the main script. In the functions i am trying to create a dictionary, which works, but python cant unpack it into the main file. My functions are:

```
def ColVal( RowName , x , sheet):
  ColA = str( RowName ) + str( x )
  ColAVal = ( sheet[ColA].value )
  return ( ColA , ColAVal )

def MakeDictionary(sheet):
  X = {}
  RowName = 'A'
  print( sheet.max_row )
  for x in range( 1 , sheet.max_row ):

    [ColA , ColAVal] = ColVal( RowName , x , sheet)

    X[ColA] = str( ColAVal )

  return X
```

sheet.max_row = 301. When i try to use the function in the main script like this:

```
[X] = MakeDictionary2(sheet)
print(X)
```

It gives the error: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)

How can i solve this?

Best regard

Comment: You're calling `MakeDictionary2`. Is that a typo?

Comment: What is `MakeDictionary2`? In any case, this happens when the function has more than one value that you're unpacking; if `MakeDictionary2` returns `n` values or returns one value of length `n`, then the Left Hand Side of the expression `[...] = MakeDictionary2(sheet)` needs to have `n` free variables in the list (or tuple) constructor `[...]` or `(...,)` for the error to not occur.

Comment: Don't use Capital Words For Variable And Function Names Please. Have a look at [PEP 8: Function and variable names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names)

Comment: yes it is a typo. my mistake. sorry. but that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the square brackets from around X.

`[X] = ...` is a syntax in python called unpacking. You can see what it does with the following:

```
[a, b] = [1, 2]
print a
print b
```

The above snippet will print:

```
1
2
```

As your `MakeDictionary2` function is returning a dictionary with more than one item, python cannot unpack it into only one variable. That is what the error means.